# How can I LOOP over several Button Views?

Tags: android, for-loop, android-button

Say for example I define several buttons in my XML file and initially set them as disabled.

```
<Button 
android:text="Off"
android:id="@+id/Button0"
android:enabled="false">
</Button>
<Button android:text="Off"
android:id="@+id/Button1"
android:enabled="false">
</Button>
<Button android:text="Off"
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:enabled="false">
</Button>
<Button android:text="Off"
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:enabled="false">
</Button>
```

Later on in my code I then want to enable ALL the buttons so ideally this should be done in a loop but I cannot work out how I can get access to the buttons ins a loop. e.g. I do not want to put several statements:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button0);
/* Do some action on button0 */
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
/* Do some action on button1 */
/* And continue with explicit statements for each button*/
```

So how can I achieve the above in a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice: Create a static final array of integers containing the IDs of the buttons, e.g.:

```
private static final int[] BUTTONS = {
    R.id.Button0,
    R.id.Button1,
    ...
};
```

Then you can iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks mreichelt. Would there be anyway to create the array in XML? i.e. have an XML array of button IDs?

Comment: Of course you can, but it does not make that much sense to me: My guess is that it would be slower (because you first have to get the array from XML vs. a static final array is very fast). And you will have to reference the IDs from your code anyway. This way it's less code and only one position to look at, not two.

Comment: I think the question I was trying to say is how can I create an array of the button IDs as XML instead of specifying the IDs in the actual code. That way I only have to refer to the XML array in my code instead of each button specifically i.e. try and separate coding from XML. Why my I want to do this? So I can add or remove buttons in the future and only need change the XML array instead of the code as well.