# generically match a button with id

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I created buttons in my xml layout, each gets an id : button1,button2 and so on.
I want in my main activity to create a button array and loop for all buttons and reference them to the ids.

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)this.findViewById (R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)this.findViewById (R.id.imageButton2);
```

instead of doing this i want something like this:

```
ImageButton btn[];
for(int i=0;i<numOfButtons;i++)
{
    btn[i] = (ImageButton)this.findViewById (R.id.("imageButton"+(i+1)));
}
```

Comment: asked many times ... please, do some research before asking

Comment: can you reference me to a question - i dont know what to search to dind it

Comment: no ... SO is not human searching engine ... use google

Comment: you said the question was asked many time, i assumed you knew where to find.....

Comment: you should name what you wanna achive then you should ask google ... generically, you wana: get android resources ids from string

Comment: `R.id.imageButton` is an integer value, you can not append a string like `R.id.("imageButton"+(i+1))`

Comment: i know, but thats the effect i want. how can i do this

Comment: http://selvin.pl/howtousegoogle666.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImageButton btn[];      
int[] btnIDs = new int[] {R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3,R.id.btn4, ... }
        for(int i=0; i<btnIDs.length; i++) {
            btn[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(btnIDs[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot take id's generically like that.

But instead of this you can take buttons in a loop if layout looks like:

```android
<layout>
  <button>
  <button>
  <button>
  ...
  <button>
</layout>
```

then,

```android
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount; i++)
     button[i] = layout.getChild(i);
```

Comment: *You cannot take id's generically like that.* yes, you can ... also there is a chance that there are not only buttons in the layout

Comment: "also there is a chance that there are not only buttons in the layout"
i wrote example layout because of this. It contains only buttons of course.

"You cannot take id's generically like that." can you share an example

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448658/how-can-i-loop-over-several-button-views
I think it'll help you

Comment: asad_qazi, i think the essential point of the question is loop on id's like them string. Otherwise of course you can add them an array and loop over that but there is no difference assigned them one by one. It's not generic.